# Restore java derby database backup

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am new to derby database and i am trying to 
 restore a backup of a derby database
 with codes from the apache tutorials. 
But it gives an error that no suitable driver found for derby , 
anytime I run the code.

below are the code snippets:

```
public void restoreDatabase() 

  {
     try { 
            String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:/localhost:1527/NSS_DB;restoreFrom="
                    + "c:/mybackups/2013-03-31/NSS_DB";
         Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
           conn.close();
    System.out.println("restore wassuccessful  ");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

After modifying the code I do not get the error any longer but the backup does not get restored. below is a modification of the above code. this is the second code snippet.

```
  public void restoreDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
     try {
            String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/NSS_DB;restoreFrom="
                    + "c:/mybackups/2013-03-31/NSS_DB";
         Connection  conn = null;
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put("user", uName);
         props.put("password", uPass);
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, props);        
         conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

the only addition i suppose is the use of the java.util.Properties object.

This error message from the Netbeans console was produced by the frst code snippets

```
Apr 01, 2013 8:39:25 PM my.gnssregsitry.DBSearch restoreDatabase
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:/localhost:1527/NSS_DB;restoreFrom=c:/mybackups/2013-03-31/NSS_DB
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at my.gnssregsitry.DBSearch.restoreDatabase(DBSearch.java:242)
    at my.gnssregsitry.MyJFrame.jButton2ActionPerformed(MyJFrame.java:929)
    at my.gnssregsitry.MyJFrame.access$1900(MyJFrame.java:41)
    at my.gnssregsitry.MyJFrame$20.actionPerformed(MyJFrame.java:591)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Looks like there is more to be done that the codes am implementing 
any siggestions

Answer (score 0):

The no-suitable-driver issue means that: (a) you have to put derbyclient.jar into your classpath, and (b) you probably have to call Class.forName( "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" );

Also, there should be two slashes in front of "localhost"; it should be "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/NSS_DB;restoreFrom=...", etc.

Comment: after making the modifications , the code does not throw any exception again but the backup database does not get restores. I have added the new code to the question.

Comment: What makes you think that the database does not get restored?

Comment: Because, after backing backup of the database I deleted certain fields and when I restored the database , I do not get the copy of the database from the time of the backup. Rather , I still have the "corrupted" data in the databasse.